# Citrus-Framework Soap over SSL sample

Tags: citrus-framework

I am trying to use the Citrus-framework to set up regression tests as we upgrade our Talend ESB routes to the latest version.   Our routes are primarily Soap over SSL secured with our local CA and requiring a certificate for authorization.  I followed the sample-soap project and got it working with overriding the certificate requirement temporarily.  I am lost trying to get it to use a certificate for the client calls to our ESB route.   I found the sample-https project on citrusframework.org but it appears to be made for Rest services and I couldn't get it to work with my soap payloads.

My end goal is to call our existing route and then call the latest version of the route and compare the XML returned with some kind of groovy code to validate they are identical.

Is there a Soap over SSL sample that exists that would help me see what I'm doing wrong with my project?

I attempted to add the sample-https code to my soap project without success.  The error I'm getting is ssl-handshake errors which I know are cert related since I'm sure I'm not attaching a valid cert with my payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration must be a bit different to the https-sample. You have to set a message sender on the Citrus SOAP web service client:

```
<bean class="com.consol.citrus.samples.todolist.config.SoapClientSslConfig"/>

<citrus-ws:client id="todoClient"
                    request-url="https://localhost:8443"
                    message-sender="sslRequestMessageSender"/>
```

The certificate is configured within the http client SSL context.

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientSslConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        try {
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(new ClassPathResource("keys/citrus.jks").getFile(), "secret".toCharArray(),
                            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslcontext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

            return HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                    .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("Failed to create http client for ssl connection", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender sslRequestMessageSender() {
        return new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpClient());
    }
}
```

The sample code is now also available on github: https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-soap-ssl